# How to merge lists in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

I need to merge two lists L1=[1,2,3] and L2=[a,b] like this: M=[1,a,2,b,3].
How can I do it in PROLOG please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try

```
m2([A|As], [B|Bs], [A,B|Rs]) :-
    !, m2(As, Bs, Rs).
m2([], Bs, Bs) :- !.
m2(As, [], As).
```

Comment: that's the (in)famous **cut**. Time ago was the only (!) way to control - to some extent - the Prolog execution. It commits to the choices done.

Answer (score 4):

You may look at this link: [Prolog program to merge two ordered lists](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/prolog-merge-two-ordered-list-3129.aspx)

This will not give you the output you need, but it is a start.

After some tries, here is the correct answer, much simple than the original proposed by me (tested and working).

```
mergelist_alternate([],[],[]).
mergelist_alternate([X],[],[X]).
mergelist_alternate([],[Y],[Y]).
mergelist_alternate([X|List1],[Y|List2],[X,Y|List]) :- mergelist_alternate(List1,List2,List).
```

You can call it like this:

```
mergelist_alternate([1,2,3],[a,b],L),!.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
merge_list([],L,L ).
merge_list([H|T],L,[H|M]):-
    merge_list(T,L,M).
```

It will work. 100% tested!

```
Input: merge_list([1,2],[3,4],M).
Output: M=[1,2,3,4].
```

Comment: This isn't what was asked.